# How do I print the point content?

Tags: c++, struct

This is part of my C++ code.
How to print coordinates of "Point pt"?

```
struct Point
{
int x;
int y;
};


struct queueNode
{
Point pt;// The cordinates 
int dist; 
};
```

Comment: `cout << pt.x;`? This should be covered in any introductory c++ book.

Comment: Did you mean "How do I print the *point* content?" There are no pointers here.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a class operator overload like string has: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%3C%3C/

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to print a `Point`:

### Accessing the internal members directly:

```
Point p;
p.x = 5; p.y = 7;
std::cout << "(" << p.x << ", " << p.y << ")";
```

### Creating a print method inside the struct:

```
struct Point
{
     int x,y;
     void Print_To_Console()
     {
        std::cout << "<" << x << ", " << y << ">";
     }
};
```

### Overloading `operator<<`:

```
    struct Point
    {
         int x,y;
         friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Point& p);
    };
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Point& p)
    {
        output << "{" << p.x << ", " << p.y << "}";
    }

//...
Point p{4,3};
std::cout << p << "\n";
```